# Deleter for Simple Expression Tree in C++

Tags: c++, expression-trees

I have created a simple abstract class called `expr_node` which will serve as a base class for any expression-related nodes.

My goal is to create a simple deleter that can delete the allocated memory from the derived class in which would be recursive in some cases.

Rules and constraints (NOTE: for practice purposes only):

- Will not rely on smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`)
- Will not rely on `std::variant` or `std::any`
- Not using `std::visit`
- Apply dynamic dispatch
- Only use inheritance
- (i'm also aware that I use recursion very often here just for the sake of traversing each)

Important enumerations:

```cpp
/// enum class: node_kinds
enum class node_kinds { 
  number_atom, unary_op, binary_op
};

/// enum class: unary_op_kinds
enum class unary_op_kinds { plus, minus };

/// enum class: binary_op_kinds
enum class binary_op_kinds {
  plus, minus, multiplies, divides, modulus
};
```

Abstract class:

```cpp
/// abstract class: expr_node
struct expr_node {
  virtual ~expr_node() = default;
  virtual node_kinds node_kind() const = 0;
};
```

Derived classes from `expr_node`:

```cpp
/// number_node
struct number_node : expr_node {
  std::int64_t value;
  
  number_node(std::int64_t value)
  : value(value) {}
  
  node_kinds node_kind() const override { return node_kinds::number_atom; }
};

/// unary_op_node
struct unary_op_node : expr_node {
  unary_op_kinds kind;
  expr_node* operand;
  
  unary_op_node(unary_op_kinds kind, expr_node* operand = nullptr)
  : kind(kind), operand(operand) {}
  
  node_kinds node_kind() const override { return node_kinds::unary_op; }
};

/// binary_op_node
struct binary_op_node : expr_node {
  binary_op_kinds kind;
  expr_node* left;
  expr_node* right;
  
  binary_op_node(binary_op_kinds kind, 
                 expr_node* left = nullptr, expr_node* right = nullptr)
  : kind(kind), left(left), right(right) {}
  
  node_kinds node_kind() const override { return node_kinds::binary_op; }
};
```

Main Highlight: Deleter

```cpp
void delete_nodes(expr_node* node) {
  if (node != nullptr) {
    switch (node->node_kind()) {
      case node_kinds::number_atom:
        if (auto temp = dynamic_cast<number_node*>(node); temp != nullptr) {
          delete temp;
          temp = nullptr;
        }
        break;
        
      case node_kinds::unary_op:
        if (auto temp = dynamic_cast<unary_op_node*>(node); temp != nullptr) {
          delete_nodes(temp->operand);
          delete temp;
          temp = nullptr;
        }
        break;
        
      case node_kinds::binary_op:
        if (auto temp = dynamic_cast<binary_op_node*>(node); temp != nullptr) {
          delete_nodes(temp->left);
          delete_nodes(temp->right);
          delete temp;
          temp = nullptr;
        }
        break;
    }
    node = nullptr;
  }
}
```

Utilities for printing a tree:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, unary_op_kinds kind) {
    switch (kind) {
        using enum unary_op_kinds;
        case plus:
          return os << '+';
        case minus:
          return os << '-';
    }
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, binary_op_kinds kind) {
    switch (kind) {
        using enum binary_op_kinds;
        case plus:
          return os << '+';
        case minus:
          return os << '-';
        case multiplies:
          return os << '*';
        case divides:
          return os << '/';
        case modulus:
          return os << '%';
    }
    return os;
}

void display_nodes(expr_node* node, std::size_t level = 0) {
    if (node != nullptr) {
        switch (node->node_kind()) {
            case node_kinds::number_atom:
                if (auto temp_node = dynamic_cast<number_node*>(node); temp_node != nullptr) {
                    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "number(" << temp_node->value << ")\n";
                }
                break;

            case node_kinds::unary_op:
                if (auto temp_node = dynamic_cast<unary_op_node*>(node); temp_node != nullptr) {
                    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "unary_op(" << temp_node->kind << ")\n";
                    display_nodes(temp_node->operand, level + 1);
                }
                break;

            case node_kinds::binary_op:
                if (auto temp_node = dynamic_cast<binary_op_node*>(node); temp_node != nullptr) {
                    std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "binary_op(" << temp_node->kind << ")\n";
                    display_nodes(temp_node->left, level + 1);
                    display_nodes(temp_node->right, level + 1);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample:

```cpp
// 1 + (2 + (3 * (-4)))
expr_node* nodes = new binary_op_node(binary_op_kinds::plus,
  new number_node(1),
  new binary_op_node(binary_op_kinds::plus,
    new number_node(2),
    new binary_op_node(binary_op_kinds::multiplies,
      new number_node(3),
      new unary_op_node(unary_op_kinds::minus,
        new number_node(4)
      )
    )
  )
);

display_nodes(nodes);
delete_nodes(nodes);
```

Output:

```cpp
binary_op(+)
 number(1)
 binary_op(+)
  number(2)
  binary_op(*)
   number(3)
   unary_op(-)
    number(4)
```

If we focus primarily on the deleter function `delete_nodes`, is it enough to be called a "proper" or is it properly deleting? Will there be undefined behavior happen?

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler approach would be to create virtual destructors for `unary_op_node` and `binary_op_node` like the following:

```
struct unary_op_node : expr_node {
    expr_node* operand;
    // ...
    virtual ~unary_op_node() override {
        delete operand;
    }
};

struct binary_op_node : expr_node {
    expr_node* left;
    expr_node* right;
    // ...
    virtual ~binary_op_node() override
    {
        delete left;
        delete right;
    }
};
```

The whole tree can then be deleted with a simple `delete` statement:

```
int main()
{
    expr_node* nodes = new binary_op_node(binary_op_kinds::plus,
        new number_node(1),
        new binary_op_node(binary_op_kinds::plus,
            new number_node(2),
            new binary_op_node(binary_op_kinds::multiplies,
                new number_node(3),
                new unary_op_node(unary_op_kinds::minus,
                    new number_node(4)
                )
            )
        )
    );

    delete nodes;
}
```

---

Here are some notes on your existing implementation.

You should not use `nullptr` for comparisons. Use either use `if (node)` to check if the node is not null or `if (!node)` to check if the node is null.

This line:

```
if (auto temp = dynamic_cast<number_node*>(node); temp != nullptr) {
```

Can then be changed to the following:

```
if (auto temp = dynamic_cast<number_node*>(node); temp) {
```

And further reduced to:

```
if (auto temp = dynamic_cast<number_node*>(node)) {
```

---

If the `dynamic_cast` fails and returns null then something very nasty must have happened earlier. I would recommend that you either throw an `exception` when this happens:

```
case node_kinds::number_atom:
{
    auto temp = dynamic_cast<number_node*>(node);
    if (!temp)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to cast node");
    delete temp;
}
break;
```

Or, just assume that it will be successful:

```
case node_kinds::unary_op:
    delete dynamic_cast<unary_op_node*>(node);
    break;
```

---

Considering the following:

```
if (auto temp = dynamic_cast<number_node*>(node)) {
    delete temp;
    temp = nullptr;
}
```

I'm not sure why you are setting `temp` to `nullptr`. When `temp` falls out of the scope, it no longer exists and setting it to whatever value serves no purpose.

Perhaps this was closer to what your intentions were:

```
void delete_nodes(expr_node** node) {
    if (node) {
        switch ((*node)->node_kind()) {
            // ...
        }
        *node = nullptr;
    }
}

int main()
{
    delete_nodes(&nodes);
}
```

---

I think it may be worthwhile for a sanity check to include a `default` item to the `switch`. Something like the following:

```
    default:
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid node type");
```